# Print first occurrence of line having "<" first character if line having ">" first character is found

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to print first occurrence of each line, which starts with "<" - only if any line starting with ">" character is found.
Next occurrence to continue with next lines.

Input file as below,

[image: Input file attached]

Expected output as below,

```
< 554033E3@rreMARS$$B$$$$$999$,YES1

< 554033E3@rreMARS$$B$$$$$999$,YES2

< 554033E3@rreMARS$$B$$$$$999$,YES3

< 554033E3@rreMARS$$B$$$$$999$,YES4
```

Below code is tried, but stuck with final way out.

```
c=1 
cat input_file | while read l 
do d=expr $c - 1 
if [[ $l == "<"* ]]; then a=head -"$d" 
input_file|tail -1 
if [[ "$a" == "<"* ]]; 
then fc=0 
else fc=echo $c fi 
if [ "$a" == "---" ]; 
then b=head -"$fc" 
input_file|tail -1 echo $b >> FirstRecord_input_file.txt fi fc=0 fi fc=0 c=expr $c + 1 done
```

Comment: what below code?

Comment: Please add the code into the question *in code format* (indent 4 spaces, or use the {} formatting button), to make it readable. Also, add the input file in the same format (as text, not an image).

Comment: Also, don't post sample data as an image.

Answer (score 0):

cat and pipe are useless, input redirection can be used instead, this also avoids to run the while in a subshell. 
Maybe following does

```
((prevmatch=0))
while read line; do
    if [[ $line == "<"* ]]; then match=1; else match=0; fi
    ((first=match&&! prevmatch))
    ((first)) && echo "$line"
    ((prevmatch=match))
done <input_file
```